# Use default keybindings in Evil in non-text-editing buffers?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I am using Evil-mode which creates a vi-layer in Emacs. This means you have different modes (e.g., NORMAL; INSERT; VISUAL). Unfortunately this also happens at times when I do not want to be in NORMAL mode. For example when an error pops up in the Cider REPL I want to be able to press `q` and exit the buffer immediately. Not `iq` (change to insert mode and quit). Same for the NeoTree navigation where I want to press `ENTER` to open a directory structure. Instead I have to press `i ENTER` (change to insert mode and open directory).

Example where I want to press ENTER on the left side, but I have to enter insert mode :

[image]

Is it possible to configure Emacs/Evil-mode in such a way that in the case of non text-editing Windows (like NeoTree navigation, REPL or Cider Errors) I can press the normal commands without having to switch to INSERT mode first?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign initial states to different modes with the variables:

- `evil-emacs-state-modes`
- `evil-normal-state-modes`
- `evil-insert-state-modes`
- ... and so on

If you'd like to maintain the default keybindings in a certain mode without Evil getting in the way, you may wish to assign that mode to Emacs state:

```
(add-to-list 'evil-emacs-state-modes 'my-interesting-mode)
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem is I do want to navigate with `hjkl` (NORMAL mode), but `ENTER` should respond as in INSERT mode.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of getting that behaviour is unbinding `RET` in the map where it's defined, that way Emacs will fall back to the otherwise active binding:

```
(eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  '(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "RET") nil))
```